# Virtualenv environment would not activate in CMD on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, virtualenv, virtual-environment

I have tried this with python 3.7 as well as python 3.8.

Installed virtualenv with pip and then created a virtual environment with following command:

```
virtualenv abc
```

I cd to the Scripts folder and run the following command and please enter... the response is on the very next line:

```
C:\Users\user\abc\Scripts>activate.bat
C:\Users\user\abc\Scripts>
```

As you can see nothing happens... virtual environment does not get activated. I have also tried "Scripts\activate" from the environment folder.

I tried it with another windows machine that I have and its working fine there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try: .\abc\Scripts\activate

Comment: `echo %PATH%` to verify the env is activated — `C:\Users\user\abc\Scripts` must be the first in the `%PATH%`

Comment: @phd it does have environment bath in as the first line. I thought it was not getting activated. I wonder why isn't the environment name showing up before the current directory path.

Thanks!!!

Comment: FYI, Python's standard library has a venv package for creating virtual environments, e.g. `python -m venv abc` or `py -3.7 -m venv abc`.